# Remove all text before and including the url from a string

Tags: php

I want to remove all text before the **first** url with http or just www and I want the url removed also. Watch this example.

```
$str = 'some text bla bla http://www.blabla.com this is another text';
$new_str = magic_function($str);
$new_str = 'this is another text';
```

With this preg_replace i can replace a url (one is with http and one without)

```
$string = preg_replace('|https?://www\.[a-z\.0-9/#]+|i', 'url_replace', $string);
$string = preg_replace('|www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', 'url_replace', $string);
```

So now i replaced the url with url_replace. Now i want to remove all text until and including 'url_replace '.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your regexp to catch text before link and replace all with ''.

```
$str = 'some text bla bla http://www.blabla.com this is another text';

$string = preg_replace('|.*https?://www\.[a-z\.0-9/#]+|i', '', $str);
$string = preg_replace('|.*www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also do you know how can i replace the url just if is in the first 10 words of the string ?

Comment: Difficult with regexp , for that write a simple function that splits a $str by ' ' and check if in first 10 elements there is a link, if true just fire both preg_replace.